# Corsair Padlock USB does not list under /dev/sd*

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have a Corsair Padlock USB Thumbdrive that used to work fine but it does not mount to Ubuntu 14.04 anymore.

It shows up with **lsusb** command, also with **dmesg** and **/var/log/syslog** file however it is not assigned a **/dev/sdX**.

This is an encrypted USB drive with pin code entry buttons on it. But I have been using it without encryption or PIN code. The green LED light in the front side of the USB indicates its UNlocked.

Here are couple of command outputs that might help;

`$cat /var/log/syslog
...
Mar 16 14:26:49 btas kernel: [263193.407994] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
Mar 16 14:29:12 btas kernel: [263335.950269] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Mar 16 14:29:12 btas kernel: [263336.042691] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1617
Mar 16 14:29:12 btas kernel: [263336.042696] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
...`

Output from **dmesg**:
`$dmesg
...
[263335.950269] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[263336.042691] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1617
[263336.042696] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0`

Output from **lsusb**:(the one listed below shows up whenever this Corsair USB is plugged in)
`$ lsusb 
...
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13fd:1617 Initio Corporation 
...`

However, none of the **lsblk**, **df** nor **fdisk -l** commands list this device since it does not have a **/dev/sd*** assigned...

Is there a way to manually assign this device a **/dev/sdX** ?
Thank you in advance for any pointers...

Comment: Could you post the full output to the files?  Use http://paste.ubuntu.com and link to them...

Answer (score 1):

I found a Corsair Padlock 2 wasn't appearing and the clue was in `/var/log/syslog`. It needed a partition table first! Resetting the key completely wipes the device, which includes the partition table.

I installed `gparted` and ran `gksudo gparted`. When it opened, I created a new partition table and added a partition on the device. Thereafter, it worked as expected.

This is a different issue to the OP but it came up in Google for me so I add it here for the benefit of others.